# Why does Bootstrap popover get squished when target is inside an affixed container?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover, affix

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flipdoubt/HsFsE/3) says it best, but I have a popover trigger that works fine. If I make the container affixed, however, the popover gets squished. Why and how to I remedy this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".popover-trigger").popover({
        content: function () {
            return $("#popover-content").html();
        }
    });

    $(".btn").click(function(){
        var jq = $(".popover-trigger").parent().toggleClass("affix");
        var state = jq.hasClass("affix") ? "" : "not";
        $(".state").html(state);
    });
});
</script>
<div id="popover-content" class="hide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ... </div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="well">
            <div class="popover-trigger" data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-original-title="Popover" data-html="true">
                I'm <span class="state">not</span> affixed. 
                <button class="btn">Toggle</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why, but setting the popover's `container` option fixed my problem, as shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flipdoubt/HsFsE/4/).

Answer (score 1):

See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flipdoubt/HsFsE/)

I am no expert but defining the size of the popover in your CSS helps ensure that it keeps its shape. That is done by calling `popover {height: x; width: y}`.

Comment: Sorry, but height and width options did not solve my problem.

Comment: As you mention in your own answer, the container option is better than doing height and width. No movement by the popover! Glad you solved the problem.